# New HP Omen 32 monitor is capable of 2560x1440 but in Windows 7, 32 bit, it maxes out at 1920x1200

Tags: windows-7, resolution, high-resolution

I just bought a new HP Omen 32 monitor and it is capable of 2560 x 1440. But in Windows 7, 32 bit, it maxes out at 1920 x 1200 when I go to the display tab in the Control Center. My NVidia display also supports 2560 x 1440. How can I get it to display maximum resolution? How do I talk to my video driver? Thanks.

Comment: How is it connected?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into same problem but think I found a solution.

In  NVIDIA control panel -- display -- change resolution, select omen monitor, then click customize. Then on pop-up window,  choose create custom resolution. You just type in 2560 and 1440 respectively, and let it run a test. Mine shows test successful and allows me to keep this custom resolution. The next time I try to change resolution for the monitor, there is this 2560 x 1440 option showing up.

I am no computer expert but this works so far. Good luck! (probably belated..)